# На опенсервере laravel не видит другой проект на vue

Tags: php, openserver

У меня есть проект 1 на vue. При команде npm run dev в консоли пишется адрес http://127.0.0.1:5173/ если перейти по нему, то проект 1 прекрасно работает.

Есть проект 2 на laravel. При команде php artisan serve в консоли пишется адрес http://127.0.0.1:8000 если перейти по нему, то проект 2 прекрасно работает.

Код `$a = file_get_contents ('http://google.com'); return $a;`
отлично выполняется.

Код `$a = file_get_contents ('http://127.0.0.1:5173/'); return $a;`
выдает ошибку file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:5173/): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Подскажите что не правильно и что нужно изучить, что б понимать что происходит.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not